# Four-(or five-)way Table Relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I have tried reading Laravel documentation and other, similar posts about Laravel database relationships, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around it and how it applies to my use case.

I run a web site for high school athletics. I have 5 tables:

1. schools - Standalone list of all schools in the state.
2. sports - Standalone list of all sports sanctioned by the state.
3. seasons - Standalone list of seasons (one season per school year).
4. leagues - Standalone list of leagues/conferences.
5. league_divisions - List of divisions for leagues that have multiple divisions (think "Big Ten East" and "Big Ten West") where leagues = parent and league_divisions = child. Note: A league would only have child records in this table if it had divisions; Most high school athletic conferences/leagues do not have divisions, and therefore would not have a corresponding record in this table.

Every so often, schools change leagues, or may change which division of a league they are a part of. (think "school_leagues")

Similarly, a school may begin to field a new sport (School A never had girls soccer in the past, but now they have a team) or discontinue an old one (School B no longer has a football team). (think "school_sports")

Also, while the state may sanction 25 sports, a league itself may only sanction 10. My web site is for the League itself, so I would also need a way to list which sports a league sanctions. (think "league_sports")

In my old (pre-Laravel) data model, I just had a "school_leagues" table that stored what league (and division, if applicable) a school belonged to for a particular range of seasons (via start_season_id, end_season_id). Additionally, in the HTML, I simply hard-coded a static list of which sports a league sanctioned and which teams should appear in that sport's standings.

However, as I rebuild my data model, I'm thinking I may need a more complicated relationship table(s) that joins Schools, Sports, Seasons, Leagues, and (optional) League Divisions.

Additionally, instead of using start_season_id and end_season_id (where end_season_id IS NULL if the relationship is still valid), will Laravel conventions force me to have 1 record per school per sport per season per league/division? (This would directly join to season_id as opposed to having start/end_season_id columns)

Any help is appreciated!

I could simply go with 3 relationship tables: school_leagues, school_sports, and league_sports, and all would join to season by either season_id (1 record per year) or start/end_season_id.

OR I would have 1 master table that joins school_id, sport_id, season_id, league_id, and (optional) league_division_id. It would have 1 record per instance, so each year I'd generate a new group of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel / Eloquent has a serviceable scheme for many-to-many relationships. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many  In your app you have several many-to-many relationships, for example `schools >----< sports` . Eloquent uses a join table (called something like `schools_sports` to represent this in the DBMS.

To handle the complexity here, you probably need a new **entity** in your database design.  Let's call it `teamseason`. There's one of these for each school, sport, season, and league.   It relates to one each of those entities, and it might have attributes like `won`, `lost`, `captain`, and other data points relating to the team and season.

For example,

- Stuyvesant High School (school) had a
- Precision Air Rifle  (sport) team
- In Spring 2018 (season) playing in the
- New York City Geeksports League (league)
- They won 10 and lost 3 matches, and the captain was Deadeye Robinson (attributes)

You'll need another of these entities for the Spring 2019 team.

A table for it might look like this:

```
teamseason_id  PK
school_id      FK to school.school_id
sport_id       FK to sport.sport_id
season_id      FK to season.season_id
league_id      FK to league.league_id
won            int
lost           int
captain        varchar(128)
```

I'd throw in division, but I don't understand the structure.

This looks like it might be some kind of four-way join table, but it's more than that. I added the won/lost/captain attributes to emphasize that it's its own entity.

The trick is to identify an **entity** for each real thing in the world of your app, then identify the relationships between entities. (It takes practice to do this well.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. The one thing I struggle with is how I can use the Eloquent Relationships with a table that has many-to-many with several tables... the table name would need to be league_school_season_sport... LoL... Would it be simpler to just have a relationship table for each relationship? school_sport, school_league, school_division, league_sport, etc.? I can't think of a scenario where I would ever need to query all of them at once, I normally only need 2-3 at a time.

Comment: I ended up going with 2 relationship tables: league_sport (simply relating which leagues sanctioned which sports for each season) and teams (joining school, season, league, and sport). Thanks for the help!